# How to FILTER a range of dates to determine monthly income?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to filter a range of dates for the string "05.2021" to determine the monthly income in May:

[image]

I assume that filtering dates for strings is a suboptimal approach. Thank you for your time.

*Edit:*

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This doesn't seem to work for me:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TEXT(B5:B, "mm/yy")="05/21", C5:C)
```

or, depending on your locale

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TEXT(B5:B; "mm/yy")="05/21"; C5:C)
```

Comment: I tried `=SUMPRODUCT(TEXT(B2:B, "mm.yyyy")="05.2021", C2:C)` but it throws a `formula parse error`

Comment: Try replacing the commas with semi-colons (as in the second formula). The use of commas or semi-colons depends on your locale.

Comment: You were right. I thought changing the locale to english would also change the semi-colons to commas but it didn't and messed things up, although some things seem to work with commas ~~

Answer (score 1):

If there are real dates, they cannot be compared to string. Either convert dates to text or compare to numbers.

Comparing to numbers:

```
=FILTER(B1:B15,(MONTH(A1:A15)=5)*YEAR(A1:A13)=2021)
```

Converting to text:

```
=FILTER(B1:B15,TEXT(A1:A15,"mm.yyyy")="05.2021")
```

If you want the result as a single number, include this formula in the `SUM` function

[image]

Comment: I tried to copy your sheet but it doesn't seem to work. Please see edit section